# Webform Boost Drupal 7

Tags: 7, ajax, webforms, caching

We are running a system with 3 servers. Each have their own database, apache and boost configuration. We are using one master two slave databases. We even excluded all cache tables from synching. To explain the problem say: **M1** is our master server, **S1** & **S2** are our secondary server. All anonymous users are forwarded to **S1** & **S2** . We used two domains one public facing **PROD** which is used via load balancer pointing to Server **S[1-2]**, **DEV** that points to **M1**.

Now we have a webform that we like to use to collect contact query. We want any submission from **S1** or **S2** should go into **M1**.

Things we tried so far:

[Webform Remote Submission](https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/molenick/1956784) This sandbox module. We had to tweak this a lot. At the end it works but if any validation fails the submission stuck in **M1**. We don't want to show **DEV** domain to our visitors.

[Ajax Block](https://www.drupal.org/project/ajaxblocks) This one solved few cases but we could not use that for webform.

Currently, we are planning to move ahead and create a custom module to handle this using core ajax framework. I would like to know if there is any better alternate or suggestion our there which can solve this more effectively.

Comment: How did you solve your issues? I'm also trying to use Boost, but none of my webforms are submitting.

Comment: We used ajax block so all submissions are going into one main server.

Comment: what other Ajax related stuff to get boost working properly?

Comment: I am not clear of your question. Could you create separate question mentioning your issues.